# Extract building geometry with overpass

Tags: overpass-api

I need to extract building geometry by coordinates
I have this, but as I use around it selects the nearest buildings too.
Is there a way to select only one? the building that includes the coordinates

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// adjust the search radius (in meters) here

// gather results
(
  // query part for: “building=*”
  way["building"](around:5,37.780495290046375,-122.47132010628351);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find anything about selecting only one building (or more generally: the **best match only**) in the Overpass API documentation, although I do surmise it should be possible.

A workaround would be to compare the coordinates of your matches with the desired coordinates, and only retain the match with smallest distance in radial coordinates.